# How transfer files to a Rails 3.1 server with phonegap API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, cordova, file-transfer, rails-3.1

I'm using phonegap 1.2.0 for a mobile development that aims to upload a file in a remote server which is a rails3.1 application.

I use the FileTransfer in Phonegap API and I do things exactly like in the [Phonegap API example](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer)
but I cannot get the file in rails.

Can anybody tell me how get the file in my rails app ?

Thank you !

Comment: Do you get any error messages on te rails server?

Comment: no error. I create a model Picture with an attribute name:string. The post method CREATE is called but the model created is empty. I don't know how to tell rails to get the file name puts in options and the given image. Options are in the header,  but not in params.....

Answer (score 1):

I have not done it, but I think you'll have to use the [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).

Add this line to your gemfile

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.4"
```

Then in your Picture model

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "150x150>", :thumb => "50x50#" }
 # you don't need the styles, I just put them there so you know you can.
```

make a migration

```
class AddImageToPicture < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
      add_column :picture, :image_file_name, :string 
      add_column :picture, :image_content_type, :string
      add_column :picture, :image_file_size, :integer 
  end
```

end
run the migration.

in you phonegap app you could do.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/pictures" class="picture_user" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_user" method="post">
<input id="user_image" name="user[image]" type="file">
</form>
```

But there might be a better way to to the form. Not Tested

**update**
you can try this as it is. The key is to send in the right options for paperclip. Make a rails app with paperclip and find the options paperclip sends to the sever from the form. Then add the options to the FileUploadOptions();

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="file";
            options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
            options.params = params;
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageURI, "http://some.server.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
```

Comment: I can't use a form. Look a the phonegap FileTransfer method. `code`var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURI, "http://some.server.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);`code`. Maybe paperclip is a good solution but I still don't know how get the filename an the file from the rails's headers

Comment: i made a update on the aswer. Start out by adding paperclip and then find the right options

Comment: If it works please accept my aswer.[look here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Comment: If it works I will ;)But I've seen in the rails doc that I have access to the request.headers which is an hash. I think it will contain the FileUploadOptions like filename....

Comment: this is the error I'm getting on my rails app:

[2012-05-15 22:36:31] ERROR ArgumentError: negative length -9 given
 /Users/luciano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:107:in `read'
 /Users/luciano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:107:in `get_current_head_and_filename_and_content_type_and_name_and_body'
 /Users/luciano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:19:in `block in parse'
 /Users/luciano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:17:in `loop'...